# How can I prove this $\langle \xi+\eta\rangle\leq \langle \xi\rangle+\langle \eta\rangle\leq 2\langle \xi\rangle \langle \eta\rangle$.

Tags: inequality

I need some help for proving the inequalities, $$\langle \xi+\eta\rangle\leq \langle \xi\rangle+\langle \eta\rangle\leq 2\langle \xi\rangle \langle \eta\rangle,$$ where $\eta, \xi\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\langle x\rangle:=\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2}$. Any help will be welcome.. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right inequality follows from $u+v\le 2uv$ for $u,v\ge1$ (indeed: If wlog. $u\le v$, then $u+v\le v+v=2v\le 2uv$).

For the left inequality, we square and have to show
$$1+\lVert\xi+\eta\rVert^2\le 1+\lVert \xi\rVert^2+2\sqrt{(1+\lVert \xi\rVert^2)(1+\lVert \eta\rVert^2)}+ 1+\lVert \eta\rVert^2$$
but this is clear from $\lVert\xi+\eta\rVert^2\le (\lVert\xi\rVert+\lVert\eta\rVert)^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Hagen for the help, I agree with you..